# How to nuget pack vNext class library?

Tags: teamcity, asp.net-core, teamcity-9.0

I'm using Team City 9.1 EAP and I'm trying to **nuget** package one of my vNext class libraries for all shared code across multiple website.

The current Nuget package doesn't support xproj so how would I get Team City to package up my library and push it to the Nuget server?

Answer (score 6):

For asp.net 5, you don't need xproj files to pack. All you need is the `project.json` file.

If you run `dnu pack` that will produce the nupkg files that you can upload to Nuget/MyGet.

So, have TeamCity run `dnu pack` as part of the build script.

You can take a look at the actual build steps that the asp.net team is using for this:

1. Build: https://github.com/aspnet/Universe/blob/dev/build/_nuget-resilient-publish.shade
2. NuGet upload: https://github.com/aspnet/Universe/blob/dev/build/_nuget-resilient-publish.shade

Comment: 404 - Page not found error for both of the links listed. Please update it.